# Why is it hard to prove about the Fisher's factorization theorem in case of continious?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I'm learning about the proof of Fisher's factorization theorem online.
Almost all the proofs of it in case of continuous is using the 
 one-to-one transformation.
But I can't　find the necessary of transformation.

I assume that $f_{\theta}(x)=h(x)g(T(x);\theta)$,then I want to prove $T(x)$ is sufficient for $\theta$

I think the proof:

$f_{\theta}(x|t)=\frac{f_{\theta}(x,t)}{f_{\theta}(t)}\\
          =\frac{f_{\theta}(x)}{\int\ldots\int_{x;T(x)=t}f_{\theta}(x,t)dx}\\=\frac{h(x)g(t;\theta)}{\int \ldots \int_{x;T(x)=t} h(x)g(t;\theta)dx}\\=\frac{h(x)g(t;\theta)}{g(t;\theta)\int \ldots \int_{x;T(x)=t}h(x)dx}\\=\frac{h(x)}{\int\ldots\int_{x;T(x)=t}h(x)dx}$

The last formula is independent of $\theta$, so the conditional pdf given T(x)=t is sufficient statistics.

Is there anything wrong with what I wrote ?

Thank you for helping me and please bear with my poor English!

Comment: The joint pdf $(X,T)$ might not exist, in which case something like $f_{X\mid T}(x\mid t)=\frac{f_{X,T}(x,t)}{f_T(t)}$ makes no sense.

Comment: The reason the joint pdf $(X,T)$ doesn't exist is $X;T(X)=t$ might be discrete ?